# Can I use Image.network on FlutterWeb?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I've been trying to display images via URL in Flutter Web using Image.network but it doesn't seem to display anything? Is Image.network even supported on Flutter Web?

Comment: Yes its supposed to work, check it carefully if you're using it correctly

Comment: I was using SKIA as my rendering tool, and that seemed to break network images. I switched to normal rendering and now it works!